# iPad email template issue

Tags: ios, ipad, email

So, I have this html email:

```
<!Doctype HTML><html>
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<table style=" width: 100%; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px #a5a5a5;">
    <tr class="header">
        <td class="logo" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px;">
            <img src="header_logo.png" alt="Logoimage"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #a5a5a5;">
    <tr style="width: 100%; display: block;">
        <td style=""><h2>Congratulations on your new website!</h2></td>
        <td class="content" style="margin-top:20px; display: block; clear:both; min-width: 100%;">
            General description here.. write whatever you want.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="width: 100%; display: block;">
        <td style="text-transform: uppercase; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CFE1EF; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%; display: block;"><h2>Account information</h2></td>
        <td class="content" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%; display: block;">
            <h3 style="margin: 0">First name:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Last name:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Email:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!CUSTOMER_EMAIL!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Phone:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PHONE!!</span></h3>
        </td>
        <td style="text-transform: uppercase; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CFE1EF; height: 40px; width: 100%"><h2>Property information</h2></td>
        <td class="content" style="margin-top:20px; width: 100%; display: block;">
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Listing Site:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_IS_LISTED!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Listing Number:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_ID!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Property Name:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_NAME!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Address:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_STREET_ADDRESS!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">City:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_CITY!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">State:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_STATE!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Country:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!PROPERTY_STATE!!</span></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="margin-top: 10px; padding-bottom:5px; width: 100%; display: block;">
        <td style="text-transform: uppercase; border-bottom: 1px dotted #CFE1EF; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: block;"><h2>your site</h2></td>
        <td class="content" style="margin-top:20px; display: block;">
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Site URL:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!SITE_URL!!</span></h3>
            <h3 style="margin: 0">Design name:<span style="font-weight: normal; margin-left: 10px;">!!DESIGN_NAME!!</span></h3>
            <img style="width:100%; margin-top: 20px;" src="http://vsbtest.com/Latestwizard/images/designs/design3.jpg" alt="Site template preview"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 100%; height: 55px; background: #fff; z-index:5; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #a5a5a5;">
    <tr class="copyright">
        <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 20px; display: block; clear:both;">&copy; 2013</td>
    </tr>
</table></html>
```

And it displays as I want (full width table cells) on major email clients - Gmail, Thunderbird, Gmail app for android, but when using the email app from iPad it does not work ok..it does not "take" the 100% width and puts all the table cells in a row. I know I could solve this by easily adding every cell in a separate row but I don't want this unless there is no other solution.

Do you have any ideea why this is happening?
I can't figure it why.
it should look something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6YqmL/1/

Comment: You use incorrect html. You have to add a `<body>`-Tag. Please first check your html for validity (W3c validator for example).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.


Comment: It's not about a typo. My bad that I forgot to add in this code the <body> tag, but that did not made any difference. With or without the <body> tag the effect is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Header tags are not consistently supported in html-email. instead of using `<h3>`, try styling them in the table cell or a font tag and use double `<br>` to separate them.